# How can you copy a link from the middle of an org-mode file that uses org-info.js?

Tags: org-mode

I'm creating an org-mode file that uses org-info.js to provide dynamic folding of exported HTML.

If I open the resulting HTML in a browser, I can copy the URL and paste it into an email that others can access by clicking but only if it's the top-level point on the page (no internal page target).

If I try opening a URL that points to an internal link (file:....#sec-2, for example), I get a "General failure.  The URL was: ....  The system cannot find the path specified."  Deleting the "#sec-2" part of the link allows it to work just fine.

FWIW, I'm using org-mode 7.5 and the online version of org-info.js.

Is there a way to have this work?

Incidentally, the URL looks like file://fully/qualified/path/name.html (or name.html#sec-2) in the browser.  When I add it as a hyperlink to a bit of text in Outlook (yes, I know; I use Gnus elsewhere), it transforms it into \fully\qualified\path\name.html.  The lack of the file: and the / to \ doesn't seem to matter; the #target does matter.

Comment: Incidentally, Outlook shows a popup version of the link when I hover over it that looks different: file:///\\fully\qualified\path\name.html.  Again, that doesn't create a problem; only the #target at the end makes a problem.

Comment: After a bit more experimentation, I see that it only happens when I click on the link in Outlook.  When I paste the link, including target, into a browser (IE8 or Chrome), it works.  The easy answer could involve an Outlook setting, but that's probably not good, as I'd need to make all the recipients of this email change their Outlook configurations, too.

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I haven't a clue about the solution.  It's not an org-mode (or org-info.js) problem, AFAIK.  When I "open hyperlink" in Outlook, Outlook replaces the "#" before the target with "%23".  The same thing happens when I "copy hyperlink" in Outlook and paste it into Chrome or IE8.  Technically, it only changes from "#" to "%23" in Chrome after I press Enter, and it never visually changes in IE8.  If I "copy hyperlink" and paste it into an Emacs *scratch* buffer, it looks fine.  Is there some interaction between Outlook and a browser that leads to URL encoding?